# How to get degree symbol to show inside my table

Tags: php

I have to add a degree symbol to my table for my F and C, I first tried to do $Celsius$deg but when I use this function I get a syntax error on my page, I am new to php and I have never incorporated a degree symbol in my tables before, any help would be appreciated.

(I'll note I have the code and the table already, however, I am just trying to get the symbol to show inside my table)

```
    <table align="center" border="1" width="30%">



    <thead>
        <td>Celsius</td>
        <td>Fahrenheit</td>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $celsius = 100;
    
    while ($celsius >= -40) {
    $fahrenheit = ($celsius * 9.0/5.0) + 32;
        
        print "<tr><td>$celsius</td><td>$fahrenheit</td></tr>";
    
    
    $celsius -= 10;
        $fahrenheit -= 10;
    
    }
```

?>

```
</table>
```

Comment: Use `$celsius&deg;`

Comment: @Nick I am stupid, I was using the wrong symbol, thought it was the $ symbol not the & symbol.

Comment: We've all been there... :P